# Update point corrdinates in the attribute table after using using edit to move points in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, xy

I have a shapefile of point locations that I edited after the original file was created, however the the attribute table was not updated with the new coordinates. So I am trying to figure out how to update the attribute table with the new point location coordinates. I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.6.1.

Comment: Add XY Coordinates is smart enough not to add the coordinate columns again if the columns exist. It will, however, compute ALL row values.  For smaller subsets of massive files, both Calculate Field and arcpy.da.UpdateCursor will take less time.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?  Did you perform a spatial or attribute edit?  What do a few rows of your attribute table look like, and what do you want them to look like?

Answer (score 2):

- Open the attribute table.
- Right click the X column header and select "Calculate Geometry".
- In the dialogue that appears, select "X Coordinate of Point" at the
  top.
- Check the units are OK.
- Click OK.

Repeat for the Y field.

Alternatively, use the 'Add Geometry Attributes' tool, and select "POINT_X_Y_Z_M".  This will add POINT_X and POINT_Y fields if they don't already exist and will populate them with the coordinates (and Z/M fields if appropriate).

Comment: Thank you, it worked great!